# How do I get all the attachments from a .nsf(lotus notes) file using java

Tags: java, lotus-notes

**Steps followed :**

Took a back of my lotus notes as sample.nsf

And then tried to read the attachments from the sample.nsf

**Code snippet :**

```
Database db = session.getDatabase("","C:\\Projects\\NotesToJava\\sample.nsf");
DocumentCollection dc = db.getAllDocuments();
Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();

while (doc != null) {
    RichTextItem body = (RichTextItem) doc.getFirstItem("Body");

    if (body.getEmbeddedObject("Request.xlsx") != null)
         System.out.println("Found BPM_Dev_Access_Request.xlsx in " + doc.getItemValueString("Subject"));

    doc = dc.getNextDocument();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No need to use `evaluate`, look up the `extractFile` in the Lotus Designer Help

From the Lotus help:

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
  public void NotesMain() {
    try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
      // (Your code goes here) 
      Database db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
      DocumentCollection dc = db.getAllDocuments();
      Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
      boolean saveFlag = false;
      while (doc != null) {
        RichTextItem body = 
        (RichTextItem)doc.getFirstItem("Body");
        System.out.println(doc.getItemValueString("Subject"));
        Vector v = body.getEmbeddedObjects();
        Enumeration e = v.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
          EmbeddedObject eo = (EmbeddedObject)e.nextElement();
          if (eo.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
            eo.extractFile("c:\\extracts\\" + eo.getSource());
            eo.remove();
            saveFlag = true;
            }
        }
        if (saveFlag) {
          doc.save(true, true);
          saveFlag = false;
          }
        doc = dc.getNextDocument();
      }
    } catch(NotesException e) {
      System.out.println(e.id + " " + e.text);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1007180 So please accept this answer as the correct one. In this way future readers like me can easily find the solution. ;)

Comment: This answer relies that the attachments are actually in the body. That may not always be the case, since there may be documents that do not have body but still have attachments. Evaluate is the only way to go if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the attachments out of each document, as opposed to the EmbeddedObjects.  Something like this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import lotus.domino.*;

public final class DocAttachmentParser implements Iterator {

private Session s;
private Document doc;
private Double count ;
private Iterator attIterator = null;
public  Double getCount() {
    return count;
}
public  DocAttachmentParser(Session s, Document doc) throws NotesException {
        this.s  = s;
        this.doc = doc;
        if (s!=null && doc !=null){
            this.count = (Double) s.evaluate("@Attachments", doc).elementAt(0);
            if (count.intValue() > 0){
                attIterator = s.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc).iterator();
                }
        }

}
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return count.intValue() > 0 ? attIterator.hasNext(): false;
    }

    public Object next() {
        return count.intValue() > 0 ? attIterator.next(): null;
    }
    private String nextAttName(){
        return count.intValue() > 0 ? attIterator.next().toString(): null;
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (count.intValue() > 0) attIterator.remove();
    }

    public String getAll(){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (count.intValue()>0){

            while (hasNext()) {
                sb.append(nextAttName());
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Works in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

To get all attachment from a notes document then i wrote this method(part of my class). 
This method takes the document and extract the attachment(Rich Text field)from Notes Document. This class also help you to know consider Example: In two document if there is same Attachment it extracts only one.

Here just you have to set "filePath" where you have to extract your attachment.

```
public boolean export(Document doc ) throws NotesException { 

if (doc.hasEmbedded()) {
        Vector<Item> allItems;
        allItems = doc.getItems();
        HashSet<String> attNames = new HashSet<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < allItems.size(); i++) {
            Item item = allItems.get(i);
            if (item.getType() == Item.RICHTEXT) {
                RichTextItem riItem = (RichTextItem) item;
                Vector emb = riItem.getEmbeddedObjects();
                String[] doublette = new String[emb.size()];
                Set<String> atts = new HashSet<String>();
                for (int j = 0; j < emb.size(); j++) {
                    EmbeddedObject embObj = (EmbeddedObject) emb.get(j);
                    if (!attNames.contains(embObj.getName())) {
                        attNames.add(embObj.getName());
                        StringBuffer test = new StringBuffer(
                                embObj.getSource());
                        test.append('-');
                        test.append(embObj.getName());
                        test.append('-');
                        test.append(embObj.getFileSize());
                        String attDesc = test.toString();
                        if (atts.contains(attDesc)) {
                            doublette[j] = attDesc;
                        } else {
                            doublette[j] = "";
                            atts.add(attDesc);
                        }

                    } 

                }

                for (int j = 0; j < emb.size(); j++) {
                    try {
                        EmbeddedObject embObj = (EmbeddedObject) emb.get(j);
                        String itemName = riItem.getName();
                        bOk = extractFile(embObj, itemName);
                        embObj.recycle();
                    } catch (NotesException e) {
                        bOk = false;
                        if (!"".equals(doublette[j])) {
                            bOk = true;
                            System.out.println(" duplicated attachment:")
                            log.append(doublette[j]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
   return bOk;
}

  private boolean extractFile(EmbeddedObject embObj, String itemName)
        throws NotesException {
    boolean bOk = true;
    if (embObj.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {

            String fileName = embObj.getName();      
                    String filePath = this.filesPath + fileName;
                    // Check if file already exists, then delete
                if (FileUtils.killFile(filePath, false, true, true)) {
                        embObj.extractFile(filePath);
                    } else {
                        bOk = false;
                        System.out.println(", error in kill: " + filePath);
                    }           
    }
    return bOk;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get all the attachments from Lotus Notes using Java.

```
Document doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
for(var att :session.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc)){
    if (att == null || att.toString().isEmpty()) {
          continue;
   }
   EmbeddedObject eb = doc.getAttachment(att.toString());
   System.out.println(eb.getName());
   System.out.println(eb.getFileSize());
   eb.extractFile("a.txt");// give file name what u  want
}
```