# Need help Exporting Embedded word documents from a Notes database file onto a local windows folder

Tags: export, extract, lotus-notes, documents

We have a lotus notes 7.0 environment with a Document library (.nsf) database file on the server.

I have a local copy (if that helps) and would like to export all the embedded word documents within to a local windows folder or desktop.

Is this possible ?

There is a software named "Detachit" available to purchase online but is very expensive ($1250 USD), per license and hence would really appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to program lotusscript it is actually very easy. From the help:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As Variant
Dim fileCount As Integer
Const MAX = 100000
fileCount = 0    
'...set value of doc...
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
If ( rtitem.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
  Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
    If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) _
    And ( o.FileSize > MAX ) Then
      fileCount = fileCount + 1
      Call o.ExtractFile _
      ( "c:\reports\newfile" & Cstr(fileCount) )
      Call o.Remove
      Call doc.Save( True, True )
    End If
  End Forall
End If
```

Or you can use Java: [How do I get all the attachments from a .nsf(lotus notes) file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850189/how-do-i-get-all-the-attachments-from-a-nsflotus-notes-file-using-java/7854740#7854740)

Comment: Notice that this routine extracts attached files, but not embedded objects.

Comment: True, I missed the embedded part). If they are indeed embedded word objects the code will not work. "For embedded objects and object links, this method throws an exception.

Comment: Embedded objects can also be extracted by converting the document to MIME and process them as a MIME objects. I am not sure this is the best way, but it does work.